# Difference between the following two sentences

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> It seemed to me that she had never sung so well.
>
> It seemed to me that she never sung so well.

is the second sentence ungrammatical?

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is better grammatically, but both are perfectly understandable and acceptable usage. Using ideal grammar is more critical or important when communicating via writing; casual (non-proper grammar) English usage occurs a lot when spoken in conversation.

Comment: Is the word “that” redundant?